# Alternate history book where Germany occupies Britain

Tags: story-identification

I read this maybe ten years ago but am unsure if it was new (library). Similar to SS GB.

It tells a tale of underground resistance to the Germans, in particular a policeman who plays the ruthless guy with prisoners but secretly he is part of high level resistance. The police become known as the lice because they work with the Gestapo.

A married couple get separated and, unknown to each other, form spy rings, one codenamed Carpenter (I think!) and the other codenamed Night watchman.

They work undercover with American backing.
I think there is a secret funeral for the policeman at the end with Churchill in attendance because to the general populace the cop's name is scum

Edit: Originally various local village people are recruited pre-invasion. Part of Churchill werewolf activities, then the enemy swarm in.
Protagonist woman is in a hidden base reporting on invading troop movements, then she has to flee for her life as German detector vans track her down, she then forms a resistance group

Comment: [Fatherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatherland_(novel))? Longer list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternate_history_fiction).

Comment: Not fatherland or any on that list, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some weeks of on/off searching I've finally found this book. Same day as I asked in here!

"And all the King's men" by Gordon Stevens. 1990.

> This is a wartime tale set in a world where the Nazis successfully invaded Britain in the autumn of 1940.
>
> The novel follows many characters, both real and fictional, with Winston Churchill, King George VI and American spymaster William Donovan all putting in an appearance.
>
> However, the main characters are fictional. Jack and Fran Masters are a married couple, separated by the war, who both play important roles in the fight against the Germans.
>
> Charles Holdaway is a police inspector, sucked into the role of collaborator

(Info shown from Goodreads)

Comment: Congratulations! This is so often the way... you ask a question and by doing so you give your brain that extra little jolt. Suddenly the answer appears!